# Ajax.BeginForm rendered outside of Kendo Grid column

Tags: kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I face strange problem with Kendo Grid Columns.Template and Ajax.BeginForm.

I have such code

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("Monitoring")
      .Columns(columns =>
      {
          columns.Template(@<text>

            @using (Ajax.BeginForm("HardReboot", "Admin", new { id = item.Id }, new AjaxOptions
            {
                OnSuccess = "Loaded",
                OnFailure = "Failure"
            }))
            {

                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Hard Reboot" />
            }


        </text>).Width(30);
      }
    ))
```

When page is rendered the Form html tag is rendered outside column like this

```
<form action="/admin/hardreboot?id=1185158" data-ajax="true" data-ajax-failure="Failure" data-ajax-success="Loaded" id="form0" method="post"></form>

<div class="k-widget k-grid" id="Monitoring"><table><colgroup><col style="width:30px" /></colgroup><thead class="k-grid-header"><tr><th class="k-header" scope="col"><span class="k-link">&nbsp;</span></th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>

                <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Hard Reboot" />





        </td></tr></tbody></table></div>
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a manual ajax request with `jQuery.ajax()` instead of putting a form because nested forms cause a problem

Answer (score 0):

No idea but you can use custom commands for this.

http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/custom-command

A custom command renders a button (you can add styles) and calls a javascript function when pressed. In this function you can do your ajax request.

Comment: I can't find any example how to call JS from custom command while in server mode. Custom command do not work in server mode in my situation.